# Can 3 phase power on grill be converted to regular 240vac?

Tags: wiring

Hi I have bought an Electrolux Hsg grill second hand. These cost £7000 new. It has a 3 phase plug on it.
Can this be switched regular 3 pin plug?

Comment: Where are you on this planet? How much current/wattage does this griddle/grill use?

Comment: In fact, can you post a photo of the nameplate label on the grill?

Comment: I thought 3-phase was only useful for motors. Why would an electric  grill be designed for 3-phase?

Comment: Found some docs.  What part of the world are you trying to plug this into?  What type of power do you have coming into your consumer unit / service panel?

Comment: Fwiw it appears  the magnetron is powered between L1 and L2. Everything else is powered between L3 and N. The reason it's fast is **it's not a real grill, it's a microwave oven** with a resistive heater to sear the grill marks on one side.

Comment: It is possible to connect a 208 3 phase to a split phase supply but we been more info like the nameplate power info. @jim Stewart 3 phase is routinely used in commercial kitchens for heat think of it this way a 3 phase MWBC is 4 wires lets just say we need 3 20 amp heaters it can be done with 4 smaller wires instead in a huge cable like what is used for us ranges in residential, commercial kitchens use 3 phase for water heating ovens and deep fryer’s all the time when all electric.